# Git branch name is not updated on terminal prompt when checking out another git branch

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, git, prompt

I'm having this command to set prompt in Bash terminal with Git branch name:

```
export PS1="\w $(git branch | grep '*') "
```

It shows the correct Git branch name for the first time after running the `export` command above. However, when checking out another Git branch, the prompt doesn't change to show new Git branch name.

I guess the subbash command $(...) is executed only once, how to make it run every time the prompt is shown after pressing Enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `PROMPT_COMMAND`. First, define a function that will
run every time a new prompt is shown:

```
function setps1()
{
    PS1="\w $(git branch | grep '*') "
}
```

and assign it to PROMPT_COMMAND:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=setps1
```

Also check out projects such as
[liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt).

Comment: tks, it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set PS1 with a single quote (which will be passed to the prompt) instead of a double quote (which only gets evaluated at creation time). There are rules when using PROMPT_COMMAND and PS1 that I was able to short-circuit learning about when I found a comment mentioning the quote issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429007/why-ps1-is-not-updated-with-the-git-branch-name